# How do I loop through or alternate this switch for my iOS game button?

Tags: objective-c, loops, ios7, switch-statement

I currently have a button in my game that calls a different ad every time its tapped.  Here is the code.

```
- (IBAction)VideoAds:(id)sender{

int random = arc4random_uniform(2);

switch (random)
{
    case 0:
    {
        VungleSDK* sdk = [VungleSDK sharedSDK];
        [sdk playAd:self];

        NSLog(@"Case 0 Displayed - Vungle");
    }
        break;
    case 1:
        [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"APP_ID" withDelegate:nil];
        NSLog(@"Case 1 Displayed - AdColony");

        break;

   }

}
```

Everything works fine and when I tap the button I get either Case 0 or Case 1 randomly.  I want to change that so that get each case in order or for them to alternate back and forth.  I do not want random. I know it's probably just a simple 10 second fix, but I've spent over an hour searching Google and Stackoverflow trying to figure out how to do it.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

iHoldCaseNo will be golbal variable which hold the iHoldCaseNo case no to be execute.

```
- (IBAction)VideoAds:(id)sender{

int random = iHoldCaseNo;

switch (random)
{
    case 0:
    {
        VungleSDK* sdk = [VungleSDK sharedSDK];
        [sdk playAd:self];
        iHoldCaseNo=1;
        NSLog(@"Case 0 Displayed - Vungle");
    }
        break;
    case 1:
        [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"APP_ID" withDelegate:nil];
        NSLog(@"Case 1 Displayed - AdColony");
        iHoldCaseNo=0;
        break;

   }

}
```

Or alternate way is to set the sender i.e button tag as 0 or 1 and according to that handle the switch case.

```
//For setting the tag use.
sender.tag=1 in case 0 and sender.tag=1 in case 1 
//to get random no,
int random = sender.tag;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Use of undeclared identifier 'iHoldCaseNo'`

Comment: Define it in .h file as int iHoldCaseNo. and in viewdidload, initialise as iHoldCaseNo=0;

Comment: It works.  AWESOME!  That solved it!  I don't fully understand why that worked, but I'm thankful for your help.  If you have another moment can you tell me what adding those 3 lines did?

Comment: I just saw your edit so I didn't add it to viewdidload.  I added `@property (nonatomic) int iHoldCaseNo;` to .h and then `@synthesize iHoldCaseNo;` to .m and it worked.  Was that the right way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the accept. its too easy at first iHoldCaseNo will be 0 so 1 case get executed and in that you set iHoldCaseNo to 1 so in the next time 2 case get executed and you do the vice verse of 1 case...